# PHP SQL Select all and print all

Tags: php, sql, select

I have a SQL table with columns ID(primary A_I),uid,title,message,time,updatetime.  The user submits a post with all these attributes, except updatetime, and I need to display all the posts on the page for admins and if not then I need to display only the posts the user has made.

Right now I have two posts in the database but when I try to display all the posts it's only displaying the first post

```
require 'header.php';
require 'navbar.php';
if($_SESSION['id'] == '')
{
    header('Location: confirm.php?state=5');
}

if($_SESSION['admin'] == '1')
{
    try
    {
        $poststmt = "SELECT ID, uid, title, message FROM posts";
        $postssql = $pdo->prepare($poststmt);
        $postssql->execute();
        $posts = $postssql->fetch();

        foreach($posts AS $ID=>$sectional)
        {
            echo $sectional;
        }


        }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e;}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `$posts = $postssql->fetch();` only fetches 1 row.

You should use `fetchAll()` or do:

```
while($row = $postssql->fetch()){
  print_r($row);
}
```

And than forget about that `foreach` loop.